# Finding source of method implementation in Rust?

Tags: rust

How can I find the implementation of a certain method I am using?

I have a function `f` I debug, which at one point calls a method `g`:

```
fn f() {
    x.g();    
}
```

My problem is, `g` is no where to be found, and it is not my code.

I mean, yes, the code compiles, but I'm trying to understand a bug, and all textual search for `"g"` doesn't yield anything.

Is there a way to convince the compiler to provide me something like *"This particular `g()` comes from `TraitA` and is located in `file.rs`"*?

Comment: That's usually something the IDE does.  Rust has the [Rust Language Server](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rls) which is used by several IDEs and code editors (including Visual Studio and Atom), but I haven't used it myself.  (I'm using Emacs, but the [support](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode) doesn't seem to be stable yet.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The generated documentation from cargo generally shows a list of all implemented traits and their functions. You could use this to find the method in question.

Simply run `cargo doc --open` to build and open the documentation in your browser. Then search for your struct

Comment: Unfortunately the struct does not exist in the project, but in a dependency.

Comment: Unless specified, `cargo doc` documents all the dependencies of the project as well :)